# Visual Studio 2022 installation corrupts VS 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 Community alongside VS 2019 Community (v16.11.19), but now both are buggy.

I downloaded the `VisualStudioSetup.exe` from official site, which updates the `VisualStudioInstaller` on my machine to version `3.3.2185.63263` and I selected these components:
(please follow the image link. my reputation is under 10 and StackOverflow does not allow me to embed images)

[vs22-components.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZbf4.png)

the first buggy-thing happens here: VSInstaller said it will download 4.5Gbs, but after downloading less than 2 Gbts, the progress finished successfully.

after opening the new VS2022, I encountered an empty project templates page, with the `Blank Solution` as the only option (the other 3 items in the image below appeared after installing component `.Net Framework project and item templates`)

[vs22-noProjectTemplates.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKpTm.png)

The situation got worse when I opened the VS2019 to continue working on my current project. every time a `.cshtml` file opens, I see this message:

[vsi-message.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtazR.png)

And the `Razor` engine seems to be buggy too. no `C#` code highlight in `View` files:

[razor-not-working.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiysz.png)

I opened the VSInstaller to modify the installation, but I found there is no VS2019 installation listed:

[vsi-noVs2019.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2pi1.png)

after many searches, I doubt it is related to `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages` folder, because I select the option to clean it after installation. please help me fix this. I want VS2022 to begin working with `.Net 6`, but I want VS2019 too , as it is my current working place with many legacy projects.

Comment: The following may be useful: [Uninstall or Remove Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: The way to build reputation is to ask good questions and/or help others by providing good answers to others' questions.